# Count Dynamically created html elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dynamically-generated

I am counting the number of inputs on the current document that have value. It works fine, except for when I have dynamically added more inputs. I can't get there values.

For example I may have

```
<input id="participant-1"/>
<input id="participant-2"/>
...
```

Dynamically created after button click

```
<input id="participant-15" />
```

I'll get the value of each one in a for loop like

```
for(var i =1 ; i <25; i++)
{
  ...$('input#participant-' + i).val();
}
```

Now when I run a for loop to check the value of each one of these inputs it only gets the values of the  inputs that weren't dynamically created. I have looked at the other questions on here and I still can't see how to apply something like `.on()` to what I am trying to accomplish.

**NEW FOLLOW UP QUESTION**
ok, now I think this is where I need more clarification concerning how to use the .on.

I have a jsfiddle here: [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YbnGY/5/)

where I create new elements and on blur of all text boxes I would like to calculate how many of the elements have value and log it. Now it currently will respond from blur event with elements who were static. It doesn't work for dynamically created elements

Comment: If you have the element id you don't need to add an html tag before. So  `$('#participant-' + i)` is better.

Comment: The examples you have and the code should work just fine.. please add more of the code. How you create the duplicates, when you request the values etc. a jsfiddle would be great..

Comment: Where is your event binding code?

Comment: Can you show the code that your `for` is placed ?

Comment: How do you get the 25 ? Change it by $("input[id^='participant-']").length

Comment: Thanks Alot everyone! After putting it in the jsfiddle. I found that when I added the new buttons I missed a piece of code. The new elements didn't follow the same naming convention, so when I tried to search for it using the selector it didn't find it.

A small over look...

Comment: Can you show us the code that dynamically creates the element? Do you have a chance to hook on that or do you need to use mutation events?

Comment: Please see updated Question i have added jsfiddle with follow up question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give it a common class:

```
<input class="textbox" id="participant-1"/>
<input class="textbox" id="participant-2"/>
```

And get it like:

```
var values = [];
$('.textbox').each(function(){
    values.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(values)
```

And to answer the edit:

The Syntax should be : **$(container_selector).on(event_type, target_selector, callback)**

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YbnGY/7/)**

```
$('.name').on('blur', 'input', calculate_total);
```

Comment: Would be better than searching the dom for $('#participant-' + i).val() many times

Comment: OP mentioned about counting Dynamically created elements, but he never show the part he is binding the event. So could't help on that part.

Comment: accepting because taught me something about efficiency and made it more readable.

Comment: Please see updated Question i have added jsfiddle with follow up question

Comment: I had to use console.log(values.length) to get an actually number, but the solution totally works for my application!

Answer (score 3):

Could also consider the use of the CSS attribute selector.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

```
    $("input[id|=participant]").each(function(){
            // something
    });
```

Comment: Please see updated Question i have added jsfiddle with follow up question

Answer (score -3):

Using a class selector will save time here.

```
<input id="participant-1" class="participant"/>
<input id="participant-2" class="participant"/>
```

Then use a simple count call...

```
var count = $('.participant').length
alert ('You have ' + count + ' Counted Inputs');
//result is 2
```

Hope you find this useful

Comment: it's not dynamic and does not change if we add other input via js